# Blank page during installation

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Drupal 7.34 on a VPS (on NodeServ): I followed the guidelines in the file INSTALL.txt, and I managed to reach correctly the last page of the installation script, where I fill the database parameters and other stuff.

The point is, after submitting the data, the script does not conclude successfully, but I obtain a completely blank page. Any attempt to install on this machine lead me to the same conclusion...

I understand that it's not much informative, anyway... Any idea would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Marco

Comment: Check the server logs, it's likely there's an error in there which will tell you what's wrong

Comment: the apache logs, you mean? I am going to see, thanks...

Comment: Ok, it seems that the script tries to load something from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ but on my server the directory is completely empty (in particular, it lacks php-cgi). Seems I need some php integration, from what I understand...